# Dragged files into Xcode show up as red, automatically using wrong path

Tags: xcode, linker

I upgraded to 7.2 recently, and went back to 7.1, but in both cases, this is happening: I drag in files into Xcode project, I create them as groups, and they show up as red. When I click on them, the file doesn't open because Xcode is looking in the wrong place. The behavior is extremely strange:

1. If I relink cpp files manually using Xcode folder button on the side bar, the file is no longer red in the project BUT now it cannot compile because it's looking in the wrong place
2. If I leave the file as red, the file path on the sidebar shows the wrong path but it compiles just fine.
3. Only when the file is manually relinked will the file be openable/editable in Xcode

My folder structure

```
My Project(folder)
    main.cpp <-- works fine
    Header(folder)
        headerfiles.hpp <-- files show up as red
    Source(folder)
        sourcefiles.cpp <-- files show up as red
    Library(folder)
        Subfolder(folder)
            libraryfiles.cpp <-- works fine
    Xcode(folder)
        MyProject.xcodeproj <-- here is my xcode project package
```

Xcode thinks sourcefiles.cpp is in

`Users/username/source/sourcefiles.cpp`

File is actually in:

`Users/username/Desktop/MyProject/source/sourcefiles.cpp`

Xcode shows absolute path of:

`Users/username/Desktop/My Project/Xcode/../../Source/sourcefiles.cpp`

Xcode shows relative path of:

`../../../Source/sourcefiles.cpp`

If I relink manually the compiler complains it can't find the file in:

`Users/username/Desktop/My Project/Xcode/My Project/Source/sourcefiles.cpp`

...but the file shows up correct on the sidebar when I relink manually. This problem occurs only for files that are in a subfolder of My Project. If the file is in a sub-sub folder, it again works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the group files AND group folder, not just the group files! The group folder has its own path that is causing group files under it to have an incorrect path.